# Saving populated values in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, mongoose, marionette

If I'm fetching a document and populating it before sending it to the client, what's the best way to depopulate those fields when doing an update?

schemas:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  likes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
});
```

controller:

```
app.get('/post/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  Post.findById(req.params.id).populate('likes').exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

app.put('/post/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  Post.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    _.extend(post, req.body);
    post.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
});
```

So in the client I receive something like:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  title: 'Test post',
  likes: [{
    _id: 456,
    name: 'John Doe'
  }, {
    _id: 789,
    name: 'Max Danger'
  }]
}
```

Which is all well and good. But when I modify the model on the client-side (I'm using `Backbone.Marionette` FWIW), and then save it back, Mongoose throws a `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object],456" at path "likes"` error.

I would think that Mongoose would be able to just grab the `_id`s out of those objects automatically, but it doesn't appear to work that way..?

So what's the best approach here? Should I pluck the IDs on the client, before sending to the server? Or do I pluck on the server before calling save?

Also, after the save I'll need to re-populate those fields before sending the saved product back again to the client, right?

Finally, I don't think I can *actually* use Mongoose's `depopulate()` method, because I just have JSON upon receiving from the client, not an actual Model instance.

Any help..? Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Mongoose' middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to do stuff like delete those properties from the JSON before the document gets saved, `schema.pre('save', function (next) {...})` otherwise if adding to the array on client only send the array of ids when updating

Comment: Thanks, I think I had tried that at one point, and I think it worked. I guess I was just hoping I had missed something in Mongoose that would grab the IDs automatically. Plus, using a pre-save hook won't work for instantiating a new model, which is sometimes my case as well. Meaning the client sends a full object to a POST handler, and the POST handler is instantiating with `new Model(req.body)`. It fails upon instantiation if I don't pluck the IDs first. So maybe client-side plucking makes the most sense for both cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using depopulate() method of mongoose, you can use underscore library of node, which provides a function `pick` and returns the opted values from given object and computes result faster [here is example](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)!

```
app.get('/post/:id', function (req, res, next) {

Post.findById(req.params.id).populate('likes').exec(function (err, post) {

if (err) return next(err);

 var depopulate  = _.pick(post, '_id');

 res.json(depopulate);

});
});
```

`depopulate` variable will store `_id's` from resulted queried document
 and you can easily send all `_id's` to client.

Comment: My problem isn't when I'm sending to the client. In fact, I *want* to send the populated doc to the client. The problem is when making changes in the client and then posting it back. At that point I need to depopulate.

But your example is still relevant, and indeed I am using `_.pick()` before saving back to the DB.

I was just wondering if there was something I overlooked, as I actually have several populated fields (arrays and single objects), so it's cumbersome to do this "depopulation" all over the place. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted 2 years ago, but i thought that it might help you..
You can override some pre-defined methods to get done what you need.

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {

    var user = this.toObject();  
    return _.pick(user, ['_id', 'email']);

};
```

Like i have overridden toJSON method to send only _id and email instead of sending whole user doc back.